# bootstrap typehead converting to ajax

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a working sample with hardcoded data. I am trying to convert it to ajax call using bootstrap-typehead. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but consol is shwoing error. Could some one help ? Thanks!

//Error

LOG: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] 
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'toLowerCase'

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z4AX7)

```
$('#selectAgent').typeahead({
     source: function (query, process) {
        return $.post('/eBus/EbusinessAgentServlet', { query: query }, function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        return process(data);
        });
    }
    ,
    minLength: 2,
    highlighter: formatRecord,
    updater: function (item) {
    $('#selectAgent').attr('data-agent-id', item.split('#')[1]);
    return formatRecord(item);
    }

});
```

Comment: Are you sure the returned `data` is structured like you expect?

Comment: Do you know how to add spin image while waiting to get data for the below sample ?

Comment: I've never used `typeahead` and only a little of bootstrap at all. But you might be able to show a loading gif in the `$.ajax({beforeSend: function(){//Show an image}})`. Then hide it on `complete`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

It is working now.

var nameIdMap = {};

```
  $('#selectAgent').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: '/eBus/EbusinessAgentServlet',
                data: 'q=' + query,                 
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (json) {
                console.log(json)
                    process(getOptionsFromJson(json));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        updater: function (item) {
            console.log('selected id'+nameIdMap[item]);
            return item;
        }
    });


 });

  function getOptionsFromJson(json) {
$.each(json, function (i, v) {
    nameIdMap[v.fname] = v.agentID;
});

return $.map(json, function (n, i) {
    return n.fname;
});
 }
  function getAjaxRequestData(query) {
return {
    json: getJsonData(query),
    delay: 1
};
// in the question this would be:
// return 'q='+query;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that because you're using ajax but javascript is has asyn (default) so you can try to using ajax this way to set async: false . Hpe this help.

```js
$('#selectAgent').typeahead({     
    source: function (query, process) {
      return $.ajax({
        url: "/eBus/EbusinessAgentServlet",
        data: { query: query },
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data)
          return process(data);
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    highlighter: formatRecord,
    updater: function (item) {
    $('#selectAgent').attr('data-agent-id', item.split('#')[1]);
    return formatRecord(item);
    }
});
```